# Print all semimagic squares

Tags: number-theory, matrix, linear-algebra

I am working on a code to print all semimagic squares [[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02983.pdf)] of a given size. I am working with the following definition:

1. An \$n\times n\$ consists of numbers \$1,2,\cdots, n^2\$.
2. All numbers must be distinct.
3. Sum of each row and each column is equal.

According to Ripatti A. (2018) [[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02983.pdf)]:

| \$n\$ | number of semimagic squares |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 68 688 |
| 5 | 579 043 051 200 |
| 6 | 94 590 660 245 399 996 601 600 |
| \$\cdots\$ | \$\cdots\$ |

If someone knows of any resources that could help me, please let me know.

#### References

[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02983.pdf). Ripatti A. (2018) On the number of semi-magic squares of order 6. *arXiv*. [10.48550/arXiv.1807.02983](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1807.02983)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) This site is for competitive programming challenges, not for questions about coding/mathematics. However, you could make this on-topic by making it into a [tag:code-golf] challenge (given \$n\$, output the number of \$n \times n\$ semi-magic squares), although I'm uncertain how much help that would be to you, given the apparent aim of the question

Comment: This is [A271103](https://oeis.org/A271103) (which itself has a reference to Artem Ripatti).